# Basic value comparisons

Tags: python, python-2.x, console, dsl

I made a value comparison "programming language" similar to a previous one I made, except this one is based solely on value comparisons.

```
# Basic value comparison
from operator import *


# Main compare class
class Compare(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.OpError = "OpError: Invalid operator or brace.\n"
        self.IntError = "IntError: Invalid integers.\n"
        self.StrError = "StrError: Invalid strings.\n"
        self.LstError = "LstError: Invalid list.\n"
        self.BoolError = "BoolError: Invalid boolean.\n"
        self.st_brace = "["
        self.end_brace = "]"
        self.OPERATORS = {
            ">=": ge,
            "<=": le,
            "==": eq,
            "!=": ne,
            ">": gt,
            "<": lt}

    # Compare two integers
    def compareint(self, command):
        if command[1] == self.st_brace and command[3] in self.OPERATORS and command[5] == self.end_brace:
            try:
                print self.OPERATORS[command[3]](
                    int(command[2]), int(command[4]))
            except ValueError:
                print self.IntError
        if command[3] not in self.OPERATORS:
            print self.OpError

    # Compare two strings
    def comparestr(self, command):
        if command[1] == self.st_brace and command[3] in self.OPERATORS and command[5] == self.end_brace:
            try:
                print self.OPERATORS[command[3]](
                    eval(command[2]), eval(command[4]))
            except SyntaxError:
                print self.StrError
        if command[3] not in self.OPERATORS:
            print self.OpError

    # Compare two lists
    def comparelst(self, command):
        if command[1] == self.st_brace and command[3] in self.OPERATORS and command[5] == self.end_brace:
            try:
                print self.OPERATORS[command[3]](
                    eval(command[2]), eval(command[4]))
            except SyntaxError:
                print self.LstError
        if command[3] not in self.OPERATORS:
            print self.OpError

    # Compare two booleans
    def comparebool(self, command):
        if command[1] == self.st_brace and command[3] in self.OPERATORS and command[5] == self.end_brace:
            try:
                print self.OPERATORS[command[3]](
                    eval(command[2]), eval(command[4]))
            except NameError:
                print self.BoolError
        if command[3] not in self.OPERATORS:
            print self.OpError


# Dict containing commands
COMMANDS = {
    "cmpbool": Compare().comparebool,
    "cmplst": Compare().comparelst,
    "cmpint": Compare().compareint,
    "cmpstr": Compare().comparestr,
}


# Read the inputted commands
def read_command(prompt):
    command = raw_input(prompt)
    split_cmd = command.split(" ")
    if split_cmd[0] in COMMANDS:
        COMMANDS[split_cmd[0]](split_cmd)
    if split_cmd[0] not in COMMANDS:
        print "CmdError: Invalid command.\n"


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True: read_command(">}}>")
```

Here's how you use it.

```
>}}>cmpbool [ True == True ]
True
>}}>cmplst [ [""] == [""] ]
True
>}}>cmpint [ 2 == 2 ]
True
>}}>cmpstr [ "Hello" == "Hello" ]
True
```

What can be improved? How can I shorten the code? Any general improvements are welcome. **Just don't change the syntax.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Removing duplicated code**

The same code seems to be duplicated in various places. You can easily define a generic function that you'll be able to reuse in all your definitions.

Here's what I have done (not so tested) :

```
def generic_compare(self, command, func, error):
    if command[1] == self.st_brace and command[3] in self.OPERATORS and command[5] == self.end_brace:
        try:
            print self.OPERATORS[command[3]](
                func(command[2]), func(command[4]))
        except ValueError:
            print error
    if command[3] not in self.OPERATORS:
        print self.OpError

# Compare two integers
def compareint(self, command):
    self.generic_compare(command, int, self.IntError)

# Compare two strings
def comparestr(self, command):
    self.generic_compare(command, eval, self.StrError)

# Compare two lists
def comparelst(self, command):
    self.generic_compare(command, eval, self.LstError)

# Compare two booleans
def comparebool(self, command):
    self.generic_compare(command, eval, self.BoolError)
```

**You don't need a class**

I suggest you have a look at [this Python talk called "Stop Writing Classes "](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).
In your situation, there is no need for a class at all :

Your code could be written :

```
from operator import *


OpError = "OpError: Invalid operator or brace.\n"
IntError = "IntError: Invalid integers.\n"
StrError = "StrError: Invalid strings.\n"
LstError = "LstError: Invalid list.\n"
BoolError = "BoolError: Invalid boolean.\n"
st_brace = "["
end_brace = "]"
OPERATORS = {
        ">=": ge,
        "<=": le,
        "==": eq,
        "!=": ne,
        ">": gt,
        "<": lt}

def generic_compare(command, func, error):
    if command[1] == st_brace and command[3] in OPERATORS and command[5] == end_brace:
        try:
            print OPERATORS[command[3]](
                func(command[2]), func(command[4]))
        except ValueError:
            print error
    if command[3] not in OPERATORS:
        print OpError

# Compare two integers
def compareint(command):
    generic_compare(command, int, IntError)

# Compare two strings
def comparestr(command):
    generic_compare(command, eval, StrError)

# Compare two lists
def comparelst(command):
    generic_compare(command, eval, LstError)

# Compare two booleans
def comparebool(command):
    generic_compare(command, eval, BoolError)

# Dict containing commands
COMMANDS = {
    "cmpbool": comparebool,
    "cmplst": comparelst,
    "cmpint": compareint,
    "cmpstr": comparestr,
}


# Read the inputted commands
def read_command(prompt):
    command = raw_input(prompt)
    split_cmd = command.split(" ")
    if split_cmd[0] in COMMANDS:
        COMMANDS[split_cmd[0]](split_cmd)
    if split_cmd[0] not in COMMANDS:
        print "CmdError: Invalid command.\n"


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True: read_command(">}}>")
```

**Use the logic and the usual programming structure**

Instead of writing :

```
    if split_cmd[0] in COMMANDS:
        COMMANDS[split_cmd[0]](split_cmd)
    if split_cmd[0] not in COMMANDS:
        print "CmdError: Invalid command.\n"
```

Write :

```
    if split_cmd[0] in COMMANDS:
        COMMANDS[split_cmd[0]](split_cmd)
    else:
        print "CmdError: Invalid command.\n"
```

Also, you could rewrite :

```
    if command[1] == st_brace and command[3] in OPERATORS and command[5] == end_brace:
        try:
            print OPERATORS[command[3]](
                func(command[2]), func(command[4]))
        except ValueError:
            print error
    if command[3] not in OPERATORS:
        print OpError
```

in a way that hilight that sometimes something will be printed, sometimes not.

**Define "pure" functions**

By defining your functions in such a way that they have no side-effects (printing results for instance), you make them easier to test. In your case, it's quite simple, you can just return instead of printing.

**Separe the concerns**

You should split the part handling user input/output and the part computing results. This does hand in hand with previous comment.

At this stage, after adding simple tests in the main :

```
from operator import *


OpError = "OpError: Invalid operator or brace.\n"
IntError = "IntError: Invalid integers.\n"
StrError = "StrError: Invalid strings.\n"
LstError = "LstError: Invalid list.\n"
BoolError = "BoolError: Invalid boolean.\n"
st_brace = "["
end_brace = "]"
OPERATORS = {
        ">=": ge,
        "<=": le,
        "==": eq,
        "!=": ne,
        ">": gt,
        "<": lt}

def generic_compare(command, func, error):
    if command[3] in OPERATORS:
        if command[1] == st_brace and command[5] == end_brace:
            try:
                return OPERATORS[command[3]](
                    func(command[2]), func(command[4]))
            except ValueError:
                return error
    else: 
        return OpError

# Compare two integers
def compareint(command):
    return generic_compare(command, int, IntError)

# Compare two strings
def comparestr(command):
    return generic_compare(command, eval, StrError)

# Compare two lists
def comparelst(command):
    return generic_compare(command, eval, LstError)

# Compare two booleans
def comparebool(command):
    return generic_compare(command, eval, BoolError)

# Dict containing commands
COMMANDS = {
    "cmpbool": comparebool,
    "cmplst": comparelst,
    "cmpint": compareint,
    "cmpstr": comparestr,
}


def evaluate_command(command):
    split_cmd = command.split(" ")
    if split_cmd[0] in COMMANDS:
        return COMMANDS[split_cmd[0]](split_cmd)
    else:
        return "CmdError: Invalid command.\n"

# Read the inputted commands
def read_command(prompt):
    print(evaluate_command(raw_input(prompt)))


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert evaluate_command('cmpbool [ True == True ]')
    assert not evaluate_command('cmpbool [ True == False ]')
    assert evaluate_command('cmplst [ [""] == [""] ]')
    assert not evaluate_command('cmplst [ [""] == ["a"] ]')
    assert evaluate_command('cmpint [ 2 == 2 ]')
    assert not evaluate_command('cmpint [ 2 == 3 ]')
    assert evaluate_command('cmpstr [ "Hello" == "Hello" ]')
    assert not evaluate_command('cmpstr [ "Hello" == "HelloW" ]')
    #while True: read_command(">}}>")
```

**Make things cleaner**

It could be a good idea to feed the comparison functions only the information they need : the first element of the list is not relevant anymore at this stage.

You can just write :

```
def evaluate_command(command):
    split_cmd = command.split(" ")
    func, args = split_cmd[0], split_cmd[1:]
    if func in COMMANDS:
        return COMMANDS[func](args)
    else:
        return "CmdError: Invalid command.\n"
```

and then, you need to re-index `generic_compare` :

```
def generic_compare(command, func, error):
    if command[2] in OPERATORS:
        if command[0] == st_brace and command[4] == end_brace:
            try:
                return OPERATORS[command[2]](
                    func(command[1]), func(command[3]))
            except ValueError:
                return error
    else:
        return OpError
```

**Don't `import *`**

[`Import *` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad). You can just as easily write :

```
import operator
OPERATORS = {
        ">=": operator.ge,
        "<=": operator.le,
        "==": operator.eq,
        "!=": operator.ne,
        ">":  operator.gt,
        "<":  operator.lt}
```

**Style**

In Python, the good there is a style guide called [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You'll find various tools to check your code if you want : `pep8`, `pylint`, `pychecker`, `pyflakes`, etc.

**Misc**

Usually, using `eval` in any programming language is quite dangerous. What if I was to evaluate a massive chunk of code with unpredicted side-effects (removing files from my file system for instance) ?
Also, you should perform a lot more checks before accessing random elements from `split_cmd` as it might be shorter than you expect.

Answer (score 6):

Your code isn't fully [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) (the Python style guide) compliant. Function names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`.

You also have a lot of duplicated code. I would suggest pulling out the common components and making it a generic function. I basically just pulled out the core logic, added a type parameter, and added in separate cases for int, str, and etc. I got something like this:

```
def compare_value(self, command, valueType):
    operator = command[3]
    if command[1] == self.st_brace and operator in self.OPERATORS and command[5] == self.end_brace:
        a = command[2]
        b = command[4]
        if valueType == int:
            # pass
        elif valueType == str:
            # pass
        elif valueType == bool:
            # pass
        elif valueType == list:
            # pass
    if operator not in self.OPERATORS:
        print self.OpError

# Compare two integers
def compareint(self, command):
    self.compare_value(command, int)

# Compare two strings
def comparestr(self, command):
    self.compare_value(command, str)

# Compare two lists
def comparelst(self, command):
    self.compare_value(command, list)

# Compare two booleans
def comparebool(self, command):
    self.compare_value(command, bool)
```